# Gamma Function Holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, gamma-function, holomorphic-functions

Gamma Function Holomorphic

We consider a proof that shows that the Gamma function $\Gamma(z):= \int_0 ^{\infty}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt$ is holomorphic on the complex halfplane $\{z \in \mathbb{C} \vert Re(z) >0 \}$:

The proof constructs a function sequence $(I_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of ***holomorphic*** (?) functions converging to $\Gamma$ for every $z$ with $Re(z) >0$. A theorem from complex analysis says that the limit $\lim_n I(z)_n \to \Gamma(z)$ must be also holomorphic.

In the proof the $I_n$ are defined as

$$I_n := \int_{1/n} ^{n}t^{z-1}e^{-t}dt $$

Question: How to show formally  that all $I_n$ are holomorphic functions on the $Re( z) >0$-halfplane?

Clear is that in each $z \in \{Re>0 \}$ the integral $I_n(z)$ has a finite value. The problem is the integrand $t^{z-1}$: Why is it holomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $t^{z-1}=e^{(z-1)\log t}$.

Comment: Ah, of course, $t^{z-1}$ is then even holomorphically on whole $\mathbb{C}$. But why we need here the $Re(z) > 0$ condition?

Comment: The integral converges only in that region.

Comment: Another way of expressing GEdgar's comment is: because we need that condition to be sure that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n$ exists.

Comment: @GEdgar: So generally, for an globally holomorphic integrand $f(z, w)$ the integral function $\int_{\gamma} f(z,w)dw$ for a path $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$ if for all $z \in \Omega$ the integral exist? Or is it a bit more subtle?

Comment: No, it's not more subtle than that.

Comment: Do you maybe know the name of the theorem which states this?

Comment: As far as I know, it has no name. But you'll find it in R, Remmert's *Theory of complex functions* (chap. 8, §2.1), for instance.